# Unable to add a List into a pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

I have tried three different approaches to add my list(content) of string values into a new column in an existing df(all_df), but every time there is some error due to the list.there are 2 columns which are compared and if same, the content is copied. i.e. it is matching both columns and assigning values accordingly. Matching is done perfectly but the output list is not coming out in the DF in any way.

I searched but was unable to find a solution for this.please help.

```
content[]
               
for i in range(len(col1)):
    for j in range(len(col2)):
            a=(col1[i])[0:5]
            b=(col2[j])[0:5]
            if(a==b):
                val=con[j]
                break
            else:
                val="Daily Update"
    content.append(val)

print(content)
```

#Output of content:
"""['Motivation Post', 'Awareness Post', 'Awareness Post', 'Product Post', 'Festival Days Post', 'Daily Update', 'Festival Days Post', 'General Post', 'Product Post', 'Awareness Post', 'Motivation Post', 'Product Post', 'Motivation Post', 'Awareness Post', 'Daily Update', 'Product Post', 'Motivation Post', 'General Post', 'Product Post', 'Festival Days Post']"""

```
#(first approach)
all_df.insert(loc=0, column='Content Bucket', value=content)
"""error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/analytics/twitter/demo.py", line 43, in <module>
    all_df.insert(loc=0, column='Content Bucket', value=content)
TypeError: insert() takes no keyword arguments
"""

#(second approach)
all_df['Content Bucket']=np.array(content)
"""error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/analytics/twitter/demo.py", line 45, in <module>
    all_df['Content Bucket']=np.array(content)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
"""


#(third approach)
dftemp = pd.DataFrame(data=content, columns=["Content Bucket"])
dft=pd.concat(dftemp,all_df)
"""error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jeshal/Desktop/analytics/twitter/demo.py", line 47, in <module>
    dft=pd.concat(dftemp,all_df)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 271, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 306, in __init__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
"""

all_df.to_excel("mergedt.xlsx",index=False)
```

Comment: Post the result of the print(content)

Comment: done @gtomer please have a look

Comment: Do you want to add the list as a row or as a column to the DF?

Comment: as column @gtomer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add it as a column, then:

```
df_content = pd.DataFrame(content, columns=['Content Bucket'])
all_df = all_df.append(df_content)
```

Comment: Its changing the df to a none type object!AttributeError: all_df.to_excel("mergedt.xlsx",index=False)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Comment: To better understand, please post the structure of all_df

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def main():
    new_column = ['', 'A', 'B', '', 'C', 'D']
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
    print(df)
    print('\n', len(new_column), new_column, '\n')
    df['Content Bucket'] = new_column
    print (df)
```

this produces the following results:

```
          A         B         C         D
0 -1.179613 -0.374270 -0.214203 -0.400627
1  0.664314 -1.339739  0.740338 -1.637909
2  1.394077 -0.709522  1.119306  0.478199
3  0.733929  0.714355 -2.518329 -1.076162
4  0.811021  1.296503  0.280754  0.053859
5  0.419472 -0.541438 -0.215574 -0.322361

 6 ['', 'A', 'B', '', 'C', 'D'] 

          A         B         C         D Content Bucket
0 -1.179613 -0.374270 -0.214203 -0.400627               
1  0.664314 -1.339739  0.740338 -1.637909              A
2  1.394077 -0.709522  1.119306  0.478199              B
3  0.733929  0.714355 -2.518329 -1.076162               
4  0.811021  1.296503  0.280754  0.053859              C
5  0.419472 -0.541438 -0.215574 -0.322361              D
```